# Anchor Tag to Middle Of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently at my wits end with this problem. I have a navigation bar at the top of my page that covers a portion of the website as it scrolls down. It contains links that are all anchors (The website is currently a single lengthy page) that when clicked the page jumps to them as expected.

However the anchor is placed at the top of the page which means that it is obscured by the menu that overlays the top of the content.

Without moving the anchor link is there someway with JavaScript or even CSS/HTML to get it so that the anchor moves to the middle or below the top by X amount so that it isn't covered by the menu and the reader can read the content.

The example I have is my website which I am currently trying to get it working on. http://kirisuteranza.co.uk. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion , have you tried padding-top:10 or something to move it down more. In the Wrapper area not the anchor.  Perhaps even the h1 tag that holds your title that is getting sacked. Nice side but overload on the CSS makes it tough to read.

Comment: Yeah the CSS is a bit much to read. Sorry, but trying out this, specific CSS for each bit. So size1of1 only makes aspects 100%, and then you can read from the HTML what it does. Saves a bit on duplicate CSS writing but a lot more HTML writing. 

I have tried the trick of putting a padding/relative anchor links but it seems to make no difference

Comment: Not to the anchor but inside the anchor you have a '<h1>' tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery if you'd like:

```
function goTo(el) {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: el.offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'fast');

}

$('#about-button').on('click',function() {
    goTo( $('#about-section') );
});
```

This will require that you give your anchors and `h1` elements ID attributes.

You'll need to include jQuery in the `head` of your HTML page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Little confused how to get this work. Leaving it as above has the same effect as a normal anchor link. Putting in a minus value before the PX jutters the screen and remains at the top. Putting in a positive value means that the anchor is actually obscured by the top of the page, and for some strange reason no matter the value, it just goes to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to have the anchor move when the user scrolls so the navigation menu doesn't cover it. You can do that with CSS:

```
.anchor
{
position: absolute;
top: 20px; /* According to size of menu */
left: 650px;
}
```

When the user scrolls it stays in the same position, not over lapped by the menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add one line of CSS-**

```
.size1of1{
    margin-top:70px;
}
```

**Edited:**

Go to your style.css file. Then Just replace all ***margin-top:3.750em*** with ***margin-top:4.375em***

Comment: Wouldn't work on my CSS as it has specific properties. So size1of1 is used very where, where 100% width is required. There is a lot of CSS because of this but makes prototyping very quick.

Comment: Place he above CSS at the end of your code or make another (same) class all div and use this CSS. Again put this line at the end of your CSS file.

Comment: But surely then I will perminately have a margin top on my div which I don't want?

Comment: i thought you could understand. Okay, see may next comment, because it is little bit large but quite easy..